# Importing functions bad, classes okay?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just a style question but I'm working on a project where the style guidelines frown upon

`from foo import bar` when `bar` is a function but not when `bar` is a class. I don't understand the rationale behind this, any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand these guidelines, too. Who set them up?

Comment: Style guidelines which contain dogmatic 'rules' with no rationale are usually ignored.

Comment: You may want to consider who set the style guidelines in place.  If it was the person who is employing you, I would recommend abiding by them.  Ignoring style guidelines is a great way to grate upon co-workers and employers.

Comment: Well, if the guidelines were written by someone else at the company you work for, why not go ask them what their rationale was? If you disagree with their reasons, and you argue the point, you may be able to affect a change to the guidelines.

Comment: I asked the people who wrote them and am awaiting reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python PEP8 (on style) is very clear on the matter : http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports

> When importing a class from a class-containing module, it's usually
>   okay to spell this:
>
> ```
> from myclass import MyClass 
> from foo.bar.yourclass import YourClass
> ```
>
> If this spelling causes local name clashes, then spell them
>
> ```
> import myclass import foo.bar.yourclass
> ```

There is no differences between classes and functions

Comment: This doesn't answer the question(directly)

Comment: Sure it does: the style guidelines refered to in the question don't conform with PEP8 and therefor can be ignored.

Comment: But PEP8 doesn't contain any rationale for this, either, so it can also be ignored. ;-)

Comment: Let me explain : the only reason I can think of style checking the imports is to avoid name collison. Therefore, it is only an incomplete answer, mainly because we don't know why the stylechecker is unhappy.

Comment: @Aya : agreed. But know he has a valid reason to not follow the style guideline. :)